# My SQL Sequence is erroring early and I don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sequence

I am doing an SQL hw assignment for an online class. The code is supposed to error on the third SELECT statement but it is erroring on the second and it doesn't make mathematical sense.

Here is my sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_first_seq
  INCREMENT BY -3
  START WITH 5
  MAXVALUE 5
  MINVALUE 0
  NOCYCLE;
```

I get an error on my second SELECT statement which states "SQL command not ended properly"; this is very frustrating because I inputted it exactly as my textbook instructed.

```
SELECT my_first_seq.NEXTVAL
  FROM DUAL;
SELECT my_first_seq.NEXTVAL
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Could you have a look at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7b0e5014fead52d0728e9a8e600f0c1) where it works fine.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run those SELECTs? SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? Apex' SQL Workshop? TOAD? Something else?

Comment: I just go through SQL workshop on the oracle website.